# Create on python array of strings from 000000000000 to FFFFFFFFFFFF and write to file

Tags: python, arrays, string, file, hex

I know this is not difficult but I am just learning python. I need to create text file with arrays of strings from 000000000000 to all ffffffffffff. So it should looks like below:

Total 12 characters start from 0 and finished by F

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you want? Do you want all 12-digit hexadecimal numbers in increasing order and in lower case (as in your text)? Or upper case (as in your title)? If so, do you realize that means 281,474,976,710,656 lines in your file? What does "finished by F" mean? Or perhaps do you mean `000000000000` then `00000000000F` then `0000000000FF` etc.?

Comment: sorry for not clear, for some reason system does not let me write example. first line of file should be 000000000000 and last line should be ffffffffffff. yes and it should be lower case.

Comment: Rory is right. The file will end up being 3328TiB (`(16**12)*13/1024/1024/1024/1024`) haha!

Comment: Except for the lower case part, your comment does not clarify your question at all. Perhaps you should show us the first few lines of your desired file and tell us how many lines there should be total.

Comment: Why do you want to create this text file? What will you do with it?

Comment: This is how it looks like: https://ibb.co/Wvk2DFq Yes I have realized that it going to be big file. It my home work our teacher asked to do it. Probably he just kidding with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make a text file `hex numbers.txt` with each number on a new line.

It will look like:

```
000000000000
000000000001
000000000002
000000000003
[...]
fffffffffffc
fffffffffffd
fffffffffffe
ffffffffffff
```

```py
with open("hex numbers.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(0xffffffffffff + 1):
        print(f"{i:0>12x}", file=f)
```

Keep in mind you'll need around 3.4 million gigabytes of free disk space. It'll take a long time to finish, too.